# Using pdf.js inside a WebWorker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, worker, pdf.js, react-pdf

I'm using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to generating images from pdf documents.

Here is my code

```js
import { pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`
// GENERATE IMAGES

const loadingTask = pdfjs.getDocument(dataUrl);
const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
const promises = Array.from(new Array(pdf.numPages)).map((_, index) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    pdf.getPage(index + 1).then((page) => {
      var vp = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
      canvas.width = 595;
      canvas.height = 842;
      var scale = Math.min(canvas.width / vp.width, canvas.height / vp.height);
      const canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
      if (!canvasContext) return reject("Can not get context");
      const renderedPage = page.render({
        canvasContext,
        viewport: page.getViewport({ scale }),
      });
      return renderedPage.promise.then(() => {
        const url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        resolve(url);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

It works OK. But during the generating process, it's blocking the main thread which is causing some UI issues.

So then I want to move all the logic to a Web Worker to free the main thread.

But when running in the web worker, there is an error:

> pdf.js:11210 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Setting up fake worker
>   failed: "**webpack_require**(...).ensure is not a function".

It's thrown from this function [setupFakeWorkerGlobal](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L1627-L1675)

My guess is it can not load the `workerSrc`, so it has to use `fake worker` with throw error. :(

I'd appreciate any helps.

Comment: This library pulls in react? Is there a reason you are using react-pdf if you are not rendering the PDF with react-pdf methods?

Why not use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist

Comment: Oh. It's the same with `pdfjs-dist`. But because I'm using the `react-pdf`, and it already included `pdf-js`.